# How can I pass data from Next JS API to component?

Tags: next.js

I have a web app using Next and another app using Node. I am wanting to pass data from my Node app to my Next one in the form of a JSON object. I can get the data into the Next API by using a POST request and that works, what I want to know is if there is a way to pass the data from the API file into a component?

Comment: Have you tried making a request from your component to the API route?

Comment: The issue is that I want my component to update when the POST request is received and use the body of the request to populate it. So I'd have to have a request from my component to the API to constantly check if the request has been received which I feel is just the wrong way to do it.

Comment: You can either make the POST request to the Node.js API directly from the client-side in your component; or you can proxy the request through the API route (is there a reason for wanting this?). For this second case, the request from the client to the API route would trigger the request from the API route to the Node.js API and would return the data immediately, there's no need to constantly check anything.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I am sending the request from the Node.js application to the Next application. Effectively I want to send data from my node app to my next API which then is sent to the component. Does that make sense? I already have the first part done (the data from node to next) I am now wanting to get that data into my component to update it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Don't you ultimately want to get data in your component that comes from the Node.js API? Is the Node.js application you mention not an API?

Comment: Yeah, the goal is to have data from node js in my next component. The data I'm wanting to send from a node is a live queue which is updated at random so whenever it is updated, I want to send it to my next component to display it.